How to authorize python script for google calendar access
My university has a site where it uploads the courses, but it lacks direct calendar support.
I wrote a python script to automate the addition of the courses to my calendar and my colleagues asked me if they could have it too. To make it work for them they have to give authorize my script, for this I'm trying to create an oauth2 consent screen, but it needs a redirect URI to work. I don't own a website and opening a port using ngrok is not viable beacuse the URL changes every time it's started, so I'd have to manually update the redirect URI. I also tried using DuckDNS but Google doesn't accept it because it's not a top level domain.
Does anyone know any other solution?

Although, unfortunately, I'm not sure about your actual situation, in your situation, the use of the service account is included in your expected result? But, if this was not included in your expected result, I apologize.

Either buy a plan for tunneling services such as https://ngrok.com/ or https://pinggy.io/ , or get a server in the cloud.
Google Cloud and AWS both offer free tier: https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/free-cloud-features#compute
